ImageSource updating in Image component => empty image, when launched from tablet
I can't update an Image in a MAUI for Android app : the previous image is replaced by a white box. I use .NET 9.
Here is the code to update the whole component:
[RelayCommand]
public async Task My(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter is Border border)
    {
        // var tempImagePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, $"temp_image2.png");
        var tempImagePath = "/storage/7376-B000/films/clavier/clavier.mkv";
        var skImage = await GenerateThumbnailAsync(tempImagePath);
        SKData? skData = skImage?.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, quality: 80);
        ThumbnailSKDatas.Add(skData);
        var image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => skData.AsStream());

        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            border.Content = new Image()
            {
                Source = image
            };

            await Task.Delay(1500);
        });
    }
}

and the GenerateThumbnailAsync is here:
private async Task<SKImage?> GenerateThumbnailAsync(string file)
{
    var bitmap = await GetThumbnailBitmapFromVideoFile(file);
    return bitmap?.ToSKImage(); <-- method coming from SkiaSharp.Views package
}

some points to consider:

initially I only updated the Source property of the Image control:
<Image Source={Binding Image}/>
but it did not work either

the skData object seems to contain valid datas: if I save it to a PNG file, I can open it in Android Studio (via the device explorer), and see the image

the image is visible when I run the application from Jetbrains Rider, in debug mode. But if I stop my app, disconnect Rider & the USB wire, and run the app from the tablet, the click on the button triggering the "My" method does not make the image visible anymore, but still the skData contains valid datas (because when saved, a correct image is generated).

ThumbnailSKDatas is a static collection with the purpose of avoid garbage collectoring of skData, if needed


thank you
PS: for the reviewers, I know this is a mix between coding and android question, but for a previous question I was rejected by stack overflow and android enthusiasts, so for this one I chosen to post in stack overflow. I have to post somewhere.
